# Ocaml: Set current working directory?

Tags: ocaml, working-directory

How do I set the current working directory on a windows system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Unix.chdir d` where `d` is a string.

More related functions:
[Unix module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html)

Comment: Well, if you're using Windows the library is still named Unix and contains the same functions. So it's different from the Windows API you're used to, but you are writing multi-platform code without effort.

Note: I actually implemented the Windows version of module "Unix" during an internship at INRIA in 1993.

Comment: I can't resist bragging a little since it's on-topic: http://mirror.ocamlcore.org/caml.inria.fr/pub/ml-archives/caml-list/1996/09/fa00da44a2bd17b3c9752ee328039bde.en.html

Comment: It says "Reference to undefined global `Unix`"

Comment: You need to link with the library Unix. Command like "ocamlopt -o progprog unix.cmxa module1.ml module2.ml". See details at http://www.ocaml-tutorial.org/compiling_ocaml_projects

Comment: inside the interpreter, you can load the Unix library with `#load "unix.cma";;`

Comment: There are certain Unix functions that are not implemented on Windows. See: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual035.html